# How to create strong passwords in Linux?

Tags: security, users, password

I wonder how I can create strong passwords on Linux (for both normal and admin users) and if there are specific programs to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string)

Answer (score 27):

[pwgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/) is one of many programs for generating passwords

Answer (score 25):

Personally, I prefer not to use password generator as password generated are very hard to remember, but one portable solution is to use [/dev/urandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)

Creating random passwords which contains no special characters, is 10 characters long:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 10` 
dyxJRKldvp
```

This works by grabbing bytes from /dev/urandom, deleting the ones that don't fit the pattern specified in the `tr` command, and limiting it to 10 characters with `head`.

Creating random passwords which contains special characters, is 10 characters long:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w 10 | grep -i '[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=]' | head -n 1
MSF4wj@vP0
```

This uses a slightly different technique after `tr` removes unwanted bytes, as the idea is to force it to have at least one special character. This works by using the `fold` command to wrap the line into groups of 10, then using `grep` to fetch only lines that contain a special character. `head` then fetches the first password that meets the requirements.

Comment: You can also use `[:print:]` for `tr` (`tr -dc '[:print:]'`), if you are a bit paranoid. The problem then will be the symbols available on your keyboard...

Comment: I found `head -c24 < /dev/random | base64` to be much more concise, produce better output, and work on macOS as well. ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347521/313358))

Answer (score 11):

I wrote this little script a few years ago and have been using it ever since. If anything, it's an interesting abuse of `printf` and uses a lovely feature of BASH that I unfortunately rarely see in scripts: `typeset`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Released into public domain
# Aaron Bockover, 2005
# http://abock.org

typeset -i length; length=$1
typeset -i rounds; rounds=$2
[ $rounds -lt 1 ] && rounds=1
[ $length -lt 1 ] && {
    echo "Usage: $0 <length> [<rounds>]" 2>/dev/null; exit 1;
}
for ((i=0; i < $rounds; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j < $length; j++)); do
        set=$(($RANDOM % 20))
        if   [ $set -le 6 ];  then o=65; l=26; # 35% uppercase
        elif [ $set -le 13 ]; then o=97; l=26; # 35% lowercase
        elif [ $set -le 17 ]; then o=48; l=10; # 20% numeric
        elif [ $set -le 18 ]; then o=58; l=7;  # 10% symbolic
        elif [ $set -le 19 ]; then o=33; l=15; fi
        ord=$(($o + $RANDOM % $l))
        printf \\$(($ord / 64 * 100 + $ord % 64 / 8 * 10 + $ord % 8))
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: Thanx for the script Aaron!!!

Answer (score 5):

`apg` is not a bad choice if you want password that can be easily remembered.

```
; apg -m 16 -a 0 -t
ByajNudgolIston9 (Byaj-Nud-gol-Ist-on-NINE)
Af}ockhuecUjrak8 (Af-RIGHT_BRACE-ock-huec-Uj-rak-EIGHT)
IakijKadmomIvgig (Iak-ij-Kad-mom-Iv-gig)
NutIlOsyahodBeef (Nut-Il-Os-ya-hod-Beef)
anMechOybekazell (an-Mech-Oyb-ek-az-ell)
VumushCummAd{fra (Vum-ush-Cumm-Ad-LEFT_BRACE-fra)
```

Note that according to [this](https://howsecureismypassword.net/), your password should be at least 12 characters long.

Comment: `apg` is available by default in Debian and derivatives although the [apg notes](https://packages.debian.org/buster/apg) have been mentioning this for quite a long time: "apg has not seen upstream attention since 2003, upstream is not answering e-mail, and the upstream web page does not look like it is in good working order. The Debian maintainer plans to discontinue apg maintenance as soon as an actually maintained software with a comparable feature set becomes available."

Answer (score 4):

I'd also add [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) which gives you the option of using system entropy to generate strong passwords with a few nice features - all using GUI. It also gives you the option of managing your passwords, and saving them to an encrypted file.

This is how KPX password generator interface looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use a non random, but is varied enough for all attack purposes... master password, and [last pass](http://lastpass.com) to generate other passwords. Here's how I generate the master password.

```
echo -n "some seed" |  openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | base64 | sed -e 's/.\{4\}/& /g'
```

and the output

```
H1sI Wpbj JE2P CdVJ A1qb 9B/e u7M=
```

now just pick a few of the sections and make a password, rearrange them, leave some out, add a character or 2 to make it as good as random. As long as you can remember your seed you can regenerate this, and recover your password (so long as you don't make too many modifications)

Answer (score 1):

`pwgen` is a wonderful little cli tool that let's you specify a number of parameters to set complexity, character classes number of passwords to generate, length, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-off script for generating [XKCD-style](http://xkcd.com/936) passphrases.  `/usr/share/dict/words` isn't a great dictionary for this since most of the words are long, but it is easily available.  For nicer passphrases you could use a dictionary of short words such as the [S/Key One-Time Password word list](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2289).

```
dict="/usr/share/dict/words"
max="`wc -l <"$dict"`" \
    perl -e '$count=4;
        $/=\4; while (<>) {
            print unpack('L') % $ENV{max} + 1, qq(\n); last unless --$count
        }' /dev/urandom | 
    while read n ; do 
        tail -n "+$n" "$dict" | head -1
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a GNOME user and you also need to store passwords for your various accounts you can try the [Revelation](http://revelation.olasagasti.info/) password manager. It has a basic password generator feature, in that you only set the password length and choose if to include punctuation characters besides letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but: As far as I understood it, there is **no** way a computer can come up with a completely random string. So I came up with the following idea [and hope it isn't completely stupid]:

If one throws a 26-sided dice, the chance to throw, say 26 is 1:26. In other words: The chance to throw 26 is about 0.04%. Further, a dice has no memory and no bugs. I came up with the following idea:

- get a 26 sided dice, where each side matches a letter of the alphabet
- get a ten sided dice where each side matches a number between 0 and 9
- flip a coin
- head means: throw letter dice
- tails means: throw number dice

Paper Models to print out:

- 10 sided dice: http://www.korthalsaltes.com/model.php?name_en=decahedron
- 26 sided dice: http://www.korthalsaltes.com/model.php?name_en=rhombicuboctahedron

**Note**: I'm not a Math Pro and I came up with this idea after reading an article in 2600 magazine which described this. I just added some of my own ideas on the basic concept.

**Also**: I wonder if this isn't just a perfect example for '*write your first brute force password cracker*'. But your question gave me a perfect reason to bring forth this idea for being discussed.

Comment: There actually are some ways to generate completely random bits. For example using the electromagnetic noise from your HDD or the variation of IO rates... 

What is hoped with the generators called 'pseudorandom generators' is that the sequence they output can't be distinguished from a true random sequence by any algorithm running in polynomial time.

Comment: You may be interested in the Diceware system.  It follows a similar idea, but uses only six-sided dice.  http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html

Answer (score 0):

I have two aliases added to my .zshrc.local file to create strong passwords.

The first is:

```
alias pw.graph="cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:graph:]' | fold -w 1000 | perl -pe 's/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g' | head -n 5"
```

The output of typing pw.graph is five lines of every character that can be typed on a keyboard with the exception of the space bar:

```
/d=|&mRq!g$QaNZ'L;CfEli,D3\)*h-jkerzv?{y"_Ic(0BtxJwF59:@G}KV1X2o>S~[#]s+W%A.<6bpTO^uP7U4HMYn`8
RIdW87{a4O3][?&rTn=m/:Y`_u*hqy2c%s@!ZPM$5to1f-.U9ClK,)'jDi0"pw>EzN^|gX~BSAJk\VFG(H<bx}+Q6#vL;e
s^H@yEo/X$|d?_jw7-n'l>m"Cb\W5.tTe0APB1D!#69[p+(8x}F&~RM`q3Q%vhfOiUZz]ucJk:)*agGV;=NY4{,K2SLrI<
$/t|!s}og5u:X~hcJUyYHf>;l<zDedL`.T*K8]CBSW[(xw+Mm^E3r16b-97%'@jVR{ZG#0p4AP=,I?\n&"a)vqNkQ2iO_F
,7n|^Y\%MpeBqvhI3mE<9zPS/~+sU`4ZoCWl&uxd'ft"kjcOy0X!{a-T_6RKiVg5Hb21D)w>@*N8;A[(rLG=$Q:.#]FJ?}
```

The second is:

```
alias pw.alnum="cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | fold -w 1000 | perl -pe 's/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g' | head -n 5"
```

The output of typing pw.alnum is every printable letter and number both upper and lower case:

```
E6wgCfVBbXjyzYQ8USKl79LqPih0e5mvGrNHd3osaW2OxkJ1RM4nFTtcuZIpDA
GTvQON1dsZSpJmegBMK6bqnEciU7k0AoV2H4Wh53zr9YRfLlDxywXItu8CjPFa
6u1Db9MfyBApZdU7gqoV2PGwH5LcxWi3JNj8nkQCIThezSlYEXsOtrmF04KvaR
VFrsGwI9yAmabEnlRTKgZO23vUq4f6LHkzQP7tMjNW8ph1exuDoBCXSd50JciY
G3r6Em5tlfjQARJx9gWHes7bCVwkzcP48KaSIXyUFBMLqT0op1uDNdih2nYZOv
```

I typically use pw.graph and copy a random portion of the line. Some passwords do not allow symbols so I use a portion of pw.alnum for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use this saved as a .html file:

```
<script>
var keylist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*_"
var temp=''

function generatepass(plength){
temp=''
for (i=0;i<plength;i++)
temp+=keylist.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*keylist.length))
return temp
}

function populateform(enterlength){
document.pgenerate.output.value=generatepass(enterlength)
}
</script>

<form name="pgenerate">
<input type="text" size=32 name="output">
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" onClick="populateform(this.form.thelength.value)"><br />
<b>Password Length:</b> <input type="text" name="thelength" size=3 value="32">
</form>
```