# Bash script to give random extension to the filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename, random

I am trying to make a bash script for OSX that adds an alphanumeric extension at the end of the file.

I can't find how to make the random 6 character. Ex filename_cod_45fg43.zip

Here the script:

```
for fname in *.zip
do
 CODE= ???
 CODESTRING="_cod_$CODE"
 mv "$fname" "${fname%.zip}$CODESTRING.zip"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
   for fname in *.zip
    do
        CODE="$(tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 6)"
        CODESTRING="_cod_${CODE}"
        YOUR mv CODE
    done
```

Comment: it returns the error:
tr: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: Better to use the `'[:class:]'` specification (see `man tr`) and skipping the redundant pipe.

Comment: @somtam hope this will help  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45406/190518

Comment: ok this does exactly what I was looking for `CODE=$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 5 | xargs)` 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mktemp`:

```
$ mktemp foobarXXXXXX
foobarAU7TyS
$ mktemp foobarXXXXXX
foobardDqS61
$ mktemp foobarXXXXXX
foobarioCZw2
```

In your example perhaps that would be something like:

```
mv "$fname" "$(mktemp "${fname%.zip}"XXXXXX.zip)"
```

But you should do some testing. Strange things happen for zipfiles that end with 'X'... ;) (needs a non-X suffix/separator which I've conveniently left out in this example).

The nice thing about `mktemp` is that it makes sure, no matter how unlikely the chance may be, that the filename did not already exist. Of course it's useless in the example above that does not check for errors in the first place...

Or you make use of `mv`'s builtin `--backup` mechanism.

(Depends on why you are doing this in the first place.)

Comment: It prints the XXXXX in the name. Is there a way to get the alphanumeric string instead of output it? Thanks

Comment: Oh. Try `"$(mktemp "${fname%.zip}"XXXXXX)".zip` instead? (Sorry, I kinda missed the OSX part of your question :)

Comment: Now it is working, but and the end of the process there are, for each file, a second file with 0 byte with the same name but no extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We go to all this lengths to avoid `mv-ing` into an existing file and to also be able to do a fail-safe creation of a new filename which really didn't exist before and be able to own it ourselves.

```
orig_umask=`umask`
umask 077; # take away perms from others + group
orig_state=$(set +o | awk '$3 == "noclobber"')
set -C; # cannot overwrite now
for fname in ./*.zip
do
   while :
   do
      CODE=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9_' | dd bs=1 count=6 2>/dev/null)
      CODESTRING="code_${CODE}"
      new_name=${fname%".zip"}_${CODESTRING}.zip
      { > $new_name; } &>/dev/null && break
   done
   mv -f "$fname" "$new_name"
done
# recover state
eval "$orig_state"
umask "$orig_umask"
```

Comment: It returns "tr: Illegal byte sequence". Thanks