# How to generate a random string?

Tags: password, string, random

I would like to generate a random string (e.g. passwords, user names, etc.). It should be possible to specify the needed length (e.g. 13 chars).

What tools can I use?

(For security and privacy reasons, it is preferable that strings are generated off-line, as opposed to online on a website.)

Comment: There are already good answers are at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25090/can-you-recommend-a-password-generator). (I use `apg` personally.)

Comment: @Sparhawk The AskUbuntu question/answers are more about listing tools. Please consider adding an answer here exhibiting *how* to use `apg` to generate a random string.

Comment: Be cautious about using random number generation on computers. Some are much less random than they appear, but telling the difference between 'good' and 'bad' random number generation is quite hard.

Comment: @Sobrique Excellent point about pseudo-random number generators (e.g. `/dev/urandom`). Would be nice to have some answers using *true* random number generators, based on e.g. [random.org](https://www.random.org/).

Comment: Joke answer: To generate a truly random string, place a new user in front of Emacs (or Vim) and ask them to exit.  ;)

Answer (score 576):

My favorite way to do it is by using `/dev/urandom` together with `tr` to delete unwanted characters. For instance, to get only digits and letters:

```bash
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 13; echo
```

Alternatively, to [include](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string#comment534545_230676) more characters from the [OWASP password special characters list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters):

```bash
tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' </dev/urandom | head -c 13; echo
```

If you have some problems with `tr` complaining about the input, [try adding `LC_ALL=C`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string#comment393964_230684) like this:

```bash
LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' </dev/urandom | head -c 13; echo
```

`tr` also has a character class for graphical characters that is a bit more readable. Limiting it to the `C` locale should produce the same kind of output as the above explicit list of characters:

```bash
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 13; echo
```

Comment: Interesting. How do you control length with this approach?

Comment: @landroni You can use the `-c` parameter to head. E.g. `head -c10 /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9`

Comment: @landroni, you could use `dd bs=100 count=1 if=/dev/urandom` to get 100 bytes.

Comment: Or do this: `head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c10` - This way is more accurate. You get 10 characters that are capitals, lowers, or digits

Comment: @Brandin, yes the last you suggested is the best approach since you cannot control directly what /dev/urandom will generate.

Comment: @Brandin Looks good. My last gripe with this approach is that what I actually get looks like this: `aXPaX9zdzcgeek@liv-inspiron:~$`. Some line break seems to be lacking...

Comment: @landroni To add the `\n` in the output you'll probably have to add it yourself. Here's a simple bash syntax shell function - make it a shell script if you want: `function genPass() { N=${1:-8}; head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c$N; echo ""; }`

Comment: @landroni Or if you want an easier one-liner, use echo with backticks to generate the `\n` for you: `echo "$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c10)"`

Comment: The first `head` command might be problematic. It will output the first 10 lines from `/dev/urandom`, which means it will stop once it has seen the 10th newline. So the length of the output send to the `tr` command is random. It is possible that there will be less than 13 characters in the output from `tr`. I haven't computed the probability of this happening, the calculations are a bit tricky.

Comment: Better do it like this: `<dev/urandom tr -dc "$charset" | head -c "$length"`

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, only that you omitted `/`. It should be `</dev/urandom tr -dc "$charset" | head -c "$length"`. And for Bradins solution: why not `</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 10 ; echo`? Is '`echo ""` more portable?

Comment: +1 Here's a quick attempt to include the other characters from the [OWASP password special characters page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters), escaped for bash command line: `tr -dc A-Za-z0-9\!\"#$\&\'\(\)\*+,-./\:\\\\\;\<=\>\?@[]^_\`{\|}~`

Comment: @Rup I'm not sure what's not working with your `tr ..` command but just quoting everything (except for the single quote) works – `tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~'`.

Comment: Someone pointed out that this could *possibly* fail to output a random string of any desired length. I figure that's very unlikely. I asked for more details [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245610/not-generating-a-valid-password).

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX's version of `tr` but does with GNU `tr` (which you can get via `brew install coreutils`.)

Comment: +1 for the `LC_ALL=C` workaround. In my case `head /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13)` fixed the OSX `tr` problem just in place.

Comment: Built this from the foundation of the answer and comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476125/9583

Comment: macOS `tr` by default expects UTF-8 input, but `/dev/urandom` is not UTF-8 encoded characters but just random bytes, so you will get a `tr: Illegal byte sequence` error. You can fix this problem by setting the `LC_ALL` env var to `C` for the `tr` command in the pipe. This causes `tr` to expect arbitrary bytes.

Comment: You can make that longer OWASP command shorter by using this equivalent: `</dev/urandom tr -dc '!-~' | head -c 13; echo` And with LC_ALL: `LC_ALL=C tr -dc '!-~' </dev/urandom | head -c 13; echo`

Comment: Actually, now that I looked at the OWASP page, it also includes spaces. So change `'!-~'` to `' -~'` to include that.

Comment: `tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 32 | wl-copy` copies the output to clipboard (Wayland).

Comment: The `cat /dev/urandom` and `</dev/ramdom`  options break when using `set -euo pipefail` in a script. So I use `head -c 8192 /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_' | head -c 13`. Given enough bytes to the first `head` is rare not to get enough characters for the last.

Comment: Isn't `tr` completely the wrong tool to use here?  It's much easier to get a predictable string length with `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 | base64`.

Answer (score 501):

I am using the `openssl` command, the swiss army knife of cryptography.

```
openssl rand -base64 12
```

or

```
openssl rand -hex 12
```

Comment: `rand -hex` will limit the output to just 16 characters, rather than the 90+ on my keyboard. base64 is better because it's 64 characters, but it's not random (e.g. there are predictable padding patterns, and perhaps some characters appear more often than others).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Note that the example `openssl rand -base64 12` produces 16 characters of output (because 256 values are mapped to 64). And the hex example produces 24 characters. There's no loss in the case of the hex since it's a simple 1:2 mapping, but there might be a little in the base64 case since padding is used. The radix does not affect the randomness, it's the way one is mapped to another that does. (and the total bit count is much more important).

Comment: The question was "How to generate a random string of a specific length" @DennisWilliamson, so while your comment is correct *as such*, it's not correct *in the context of this question*.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: In that case, neither is this answer.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.

urandom, pwgen, gpw, etc may or may not be available on your system; also in different environments, a policy that works on one may not work on another. It would be a pretty dysfunctional setup to not have openssl.

Even better:

openssl rand -base64 32 | tr -d /=+ | cut -c -16

That'll give you 32 char minus non-alphanum's and trimmed to 16 char length. Makes it easy to deal with as an admin. Users only have alphanums (which they tend to appreciate). The length is long enough that the removal of special chars don't overly impact the entropy. Golden.

Comment: This worked also straight forward on a mac

Comment: I am here to initialize IV, and this is what i was missing

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Note that according to its manual, the `openssl rand` command is still a pseudo-random generator, therefore not cryptographically secure. This suited my needs, but may not suit the need of all applications, e.g. initializing IV as mentioned in another comment.

Comment: Note that the manual says `openssl rand` is a _cryptographically secure_ pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG).

Comment: You probably want to use `openssl rand 64 | openssl enc -A -base64` for longer strings, otherwise it will cut of at 80 characters because of backward compatibility with old terminals.

Comment: Beware this can generate not valid symbols for passwords like \n

Answer (score 212):

To generate a random password you can use **`pwgen`**:

> `pwgen` generates random, meaningless but pronounceable passwords.
> These passwords contain either only lowercase letters, or upper and lower case mixed, or digits thrown in. Uppercase letters and digits are placed in a way that eases remembering their position when memorizing only the word.

Generate 7 passwords of length 13:

```shellsession
geek@liv-inspiron:~$ pwgen 13 7
Eu7Teadiphaec giepahl3Oyaiy iecoo9Aetaib4 phaiChae6Eivi athoo3igee8Co
Iphu4ufeDeelo aesoYi2lie9he
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can avoid reducing entropy by using the `-s` argument (i.e. generate more secure, completely random but hard to remember passwords):

```shellsession
geek@liv-inspiron:~$ pwgen -s 13 7
eAfycrPlM4cYv 4MRXmZmyIVNBp D8y71iqjG7Zq7 FQRHcserl4R8O yRCUtPtV3dsqV
0vJpp2h0OrgF1 QTp7MKtJyTrjz
```

For `brew` users, see [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pwgen).

---

To generate random user names you can use **`gpw`**:

> This package generates pronounceable passwords. It uses the statistics of
> three-letter combinations (trigraphs) taken from whatever dictionaries you
> feed it.

Generate 7 passwords (user names) of length 13:

```shellsession
geek@liv-inspiron:~$ gpw 7 13
sreepoidahsas
risadiestinge
ntodynesssine
deodstestress
natinglumperm
riasigentspir
enderiferback
```

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel.  If you don't want the reduced entropy of the "pronounceable" constraint, simply use `pwgen -s`.

Comment: Too bad `pwgen` is not included as part of standard bash release.

Answer (score 48):

Inspired by Pablo Repetto I ended up with this *easy to remember* solution:

```
shuf -er -n20  {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} | tr -d '\n'
```

`-e` echoes the result

`-r` allows any character to appear multiple times

`-n20` requests a random string with a length of 20 characters

`{A..Z} {a..z} {0..9}` defines the allowed char classes

`shuf` is part of coreutils and widely available or at least been ported.

Comment: To run this in fish shell, use `bash -c 'shuf -zer -n20  {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9}'`

Comment: `&& printf "\n"`

Comment: Can you make it guarantee at least one selection from each character class? I need to implement the [AWS IAM user default password policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_account-policy.html). Minimum of three of the following mix of character types: uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and non-alphanumeric character (`! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = [ ] { } | '`).

Answer (score 45):

Here is how, I do it. It generates 10 characters random string. You can optimize it by replacing the "fold", with other string processing tools.

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
```

Comment: Note that you also add a newline at the end. To fix that, and optimize by replacing `fold -w 10 | head -n 1` with `head -c10`

Comment: I've been using this for years however in macOS Big Sur it breaks with "Input error"

Comment: add `LC_ALL` as suggested in another answer: `cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1`

Answer (score 30):

To generate password with the highest entropy possible with standard Linux tools that are built into every distribution I use:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -cd "[:print:]" | head -c 32; echo
```

This outputs all of the ASCII printable characters - from 32 (space) to 126 (tilde, `~`). The password length can be controlled with the `head`'s `-c` flag. There are also other possible character sets in `tr` (to not include the space, just characters 33-126, use `[:graph:]`).

Comment: In what way is this different from the existing answers?  Specifically, [herbert's](/a/230676/) comes to mind.

Comment: @Fox His solution uses hardcoded list of characters, which is not an encouraged programming practice because of code readability, compactness and cleanliness. Also some of the special printable ASCII characters could be interpreted by bash, not to mention the most obvious drawback of his one liner - if maximum entropy is desired, can one be sure that all of the available characters are included in the list? And that there are no duplicates which could possibly alter the tr's behaviour? His answer should be replaced by mine since you asked :)

Comment: Many if not most web sites have restrictions on the characters that can be in a password,  so hard-coding '[:print:]' doesn't feel any better to me than hard-coding the OWASP password special character list. I feel that almost every answer here could be improved by using a variable, but that is such a minor change that I'd only suggest an edit

Comment: `< /dev/urandom tr -cd '[:graph:]'| tr  -d '\\' | head -c 32; echo` if you dont want `\` characters in generated string. `\` because is an escape character in many languages causes problems

Comment: ```< /dev/urandom tr -cd "[:print:]" | tr -d ' \\/\`\|' | head -c 32; echo``` to exclude | \ / ` and space

Comment: @RyanKrage `:graph:` already excludes space, so a better solution than `:print:`.

Answer (score 25):

Use the `xxd` command to specify length (via `-l`),
which works both in Linux and macOS. 
See the [xxd(1)](https://manpages.org/xxd) man page
or the [Linux xxd Command Tutorial for Beginners (with Examples)](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-xxd-command/).

```bash
xxd -l16 -ps /dev/urandom
```

Comment: This generates a random _hexadecimal_ string. In a good password we'd like to have 2*26 Latin letters and 10 digits.

Comment: This is the 5-star answer, neat!

Comment: `xxd: invalid number '/dev/urandom'` on Alpine Linux running in docker. Without `-s` is ok.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the level of randomness you want, you could simply go with bash's (also `zsh` and `ksh`, possibly others) builtin `$RANDOM` variable:

```
$ echo $RANDOM | tr '[0-9]' '[a-z]'
bfeci
$ echo $RANDOM | tr '[0-9]' '[a-z]'
cijjj
```

The methods reading directly from `/dev/urandom` are far simpler, but for the sake of completion, you could also use `$RANDOM`:

```
echo $(for((i=1;i<=13;i++)); do printf '%s' "${RANDOM:0:1}"; done) | tr '[0-9]' '[a-z]'
```

**Important**: this solution will only produce random strings using the first 10 letters of the alphabet. Whether or not that is enough for you depends on what you need this for.

Comment: How do you control the length of the generated string?

Comment: @landroni I don't think you can short of using a loop until you get the right length. `$RANDOM` will print a number between 0 and 32767.

Comment: I've tried running the command some 20 times, and I can never get anything longer than 4-5 chars...

Comment: @landroni yes, that's what I said, it generates numbers between 0 and 32767, so 5 digits will be the max. If you need longer ones or need to be able to specify the length, please edit your question and make that clear.

Comment: I've now clarified the question to include length requirement.

Comment: @landroni thanks, I've added a way to specify length but it's not very good. I'd just use something like `rand=$(head -c 100 /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c13)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. The loop only generates strings with small characters. Is it possible to have capitals and/or numbers in the resulting string?

Comment: @landroni probably, but it's not worth the effort. Just use `/dev/urandom` as the other answers (and my previous comment) suggest instead.

Comment: @landroni `echo $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM|head -c13`.

Comment: Beware that this solution is limited to the 10 first characters of the alphabet.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou very good point. I added this to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`APG` is included by default on some Linux distributions.

To generate passwords from size 5 to 10 in subsets Special, Numeric, Capital and Lower, the command is:

```
apg -MSNCL -m 5 -x 10
```

And returns

```
@OpVeyhym9
3:Glul
3DroomIc?
hed&Os0
NefIj%Ob3
35Quok}
```

As said by @landroni in comment.

Comment: Here are the options to generate random 14 letter passwords containing lots of special characters: `apg -a1 -m14`

Comment: Generate single password: ```apg -MSNCL -n 1 -m 5 -x 10```

Comment: See [apg's complete special character set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1472405/how-to-see-the-complete-special-symbol-set-that-apg-automated-password-genera).

Answer (score 10):

I use:

`base64 < /dev/urandom | tr -d 'O0Il1+/' | head -c 44; printf '\n'`

This gives me 57 possible characters. The string can be copy-pasted (removed `+` and `/`) or printed and retyped as the difficult to distinguish characters (`I1lO0`) have been removed.

- 44 characters gives me: log<sub>2</sub>(57<sup>44</sup>) > 256.64 bits of entropy
- 22 characters gives me: log<sub>2</sub>(57<sup>22</sup>) > 128.32 bits of entropy

I like this because:

- the command is simple to type and memorable
- it uses standard system tools - no extra binaries
- doesn't "waste" much randomness (uses 89% of the random bits it receives vs ~24% for solutions directly piping to tr)
- 22 and 44 characters pair quite nicely (just above even) common power of two breakpoints
- the output can be easily selected and pasted or printed and retyped with minimal human error rates
- shorter than hex encoded (32 and 64 instead of 22 and 44) solutions such as md5sum/sha1sum, etc.

Credit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230676/9583 and especially the comments for my initial inspiration.

Comment: If you _need_ numbers/special characters - typically there will be a number, if not you can safely append `1` without reducing entropy (while generating a new one to get one w/a number _does_ reduce entropy). You can also safely append a `!` without reducing entropy. Neither scheme increases entropy worth anything either, but could bring the generated string into compliance with older password requirements.

Comment: And it works on macOS!

Answer (score 6):

@Brandin explained in a comment to another answer how to get at most 100 bytes from `/dev/urandom` using `head -c 100`. Another way to do this is with `dd`:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | dd bs=100 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

The `2>/dev/null` at the end of the `dd` command is to suppress the "... records in / ... records out" output.

I'm not aware of any substantial advantages/disadvantages between these two methods.

I had an issue with both methods of `tr` complaining about the input. I thought this was because it didn't like receiving binary input, and hence suggested first filtering `/dev/random` with `iconv -c -t US`. However, Gilles suggested a different diagnosis and solution, which works for me:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | dd bs=100 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: For some reason the `iconv` solution maxes one CPU core and doesn't yield an output (I waited some 10s before killing it)...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 system iconv is provided by `libc-bin` 2.19. I'm not sure if it's the same iconv...

Comment: `tr` supports binary input. However a range like `A-Z` may be influenced by locale settings. Try `LC_ALL=C tr …`

Comment: @Gilles According to the POSIX spec it doesn't "support binary input". Only GNU `tr` does because it doesn't support multibyte at all (e.g. last time I checked it changing case was implemented by simply setting the sixth bit of every byte). Other systems (e.g. BSD) do support multibyte and this will fail there since the chance that a random input stream is also a valid multibyte stream is very small in most encodings. GNU *may* add multibyte support at any given moment, at which point this will fail. Of course, setting `LC_ALL=C` will fix that.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker POSIX does require `tr` to process binary input (in the C locale). (Well, ok, it only says explicitly that null bytes are to be supported, it doesn't say that non-empty files not ending with a newline character are to be supported, but in practice that's always the case as well.)

Comment: @Gilles In the C locale *any* byte is a character with the exception of the NUL byte; but not so in multibyte encodings; how is it supposed to handle invalid UTF-8 sequences (which are almost guaranteed to occur with a random input)? The sane thing to do is to show an error and exit (which is what BSD `tr` will do). It seems to me that in 2016 we should assume multibyte by default, rather than as an afterthought, and reasoning from that, `tr` doesn't really support binary input (with the exception of the NUL byte).

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of `md5` tools that has precisely this purpose. In the case of creating a completely random password you can use the `md5pass`. It is a very simple tool to use and very helpful, since you can use "normal text" together with a "salt" to jump-bit construction of the same password that you can recover afterwards, or alternatively you may want to get a completely random password all the time. The general usage is:

```
md5pass [password] [salt]
```

where `password` is a chosen word that will be used for the construction of the random string and `salt` is the jump in bytes to be used. Like this:

```
md5pass word

$1$.MUittVW$j.XDTF1QRnxqFdXRUiSLs0
```

This will create a "a random sequence" password for you to use. If you use no `salt`, then you may not be able to recreate this same string afterwards.

However if you use a `salt` like this:

```
md5pass word 512

$1$512$.0jcLPQ83jgszaPT8xzds0
```

then you can create a sequence which you can recover if you use the word in conjunction with the same salt (or jump) if it was originally defined.

Comment: When a `salt` is being used, this sounds similar to the PasswordMaker approach...

Comment: -Yes May sound similar to one maker password, but the difference is that it is not a commercial program or anything, because the set of md5 tools, "md5pass, md5sum, md5sum.textutils" dealt with here are concerned and are available the system at no cost some !!!

Comment: I actually had in mind [PasswordMaker](http://passwordmaker.org/), which is also open-source and non-commercial.

Comment: If you don't have (or like) `md5pass`, a very similar idea also works with `openssl`: `openssl passwd <BLABLA>`, where `<BLABLA>` is an arbitrary string. This command just generates a hash of that string using the `crypt` algorithm by default. Old-fashioned, no high security, but for quick-and-dirty applications (like temporary accounts) may be acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

These two commands generate random passwords and passphrases, respectively.

```
shuf --random-source=/dev/urandom --repeat --head-count=20 file_with_characters | tr --delete '\n'

shuf --random-source=/dev/urandom --repeat --head-count=7 file_with_words | tr '\n' ' '
```

The password generator requires a file_with_characters containing all the characters you want the password to use, one character per line, and exactly one time each. The file must not contain blank lines, and lines must be newline-terminated.

The passphrase generator requires a file_with_words containing all the words you want the passphrase to use, one word per line, and exactly one time each. The file must not contain blank lines, and lines must be newline-terminated.

The --head-count option specifies the length of the password--in characters--or passphrase--in words.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that piping /dev/urandom to tr on macOS didn't work. Here's another way:

```
set="abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
n=6
rand=""
for i in `seq 1 $n`; do
    char=${set:$RANDOM % ${#set}:1}
    rand+=$char
done
echo $rand
```

Comment: Check the last example of my answer. It does not use tr.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494931/203075

Answer (score 4):

I would like to contribute my usual command to generate a password

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -n 1 |tr -dc '[:alnum:]' |cut -c -13
b0R55751vWW9V
```

To configure the length of the password, change the number in the cut command to the length that you require, for example, 24 character

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -n 1 |tr -dc '[:alnum:]' |cut -c -24
WFBhVHuKbrnRhd5kdWXPzmZG
```

Don't want confusing 0 or O, 1 or l? Filter it out with another `tr`

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -n 1 |tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | tr -d '0O1l'|cut -c -24
JuCphwvhrhppD9wVqfpP2beG
```

I personally never prefer special character in password, that is why I only choose `[:alnum:]` for my password generator

Comment: `urandom` → `base64` has already been given as an answer. And, in fact, that previous answer also included removing ‘O’, ‘0’, ‘I’, ‘l’ and ‘1’. And why do you need both `head` and `cut`?

Answer (score 3):

`pwgen`, as everyone else has said, for passwords.

Lowercase only, secure, at least 1 number, 8 characters, 1 result

```bsh
$ pwgen -snA 8 1
d14o5wgh
```

Same, but at least 1 uppercase

```bsh
$ pwgen -csn 8 1
bMxDxcr4
```

A diceware cli for usernames, and passwords if you want, for something a little more recollection friendly; I use the [pip package](https://github.com/ulif/diceware) `diceware`, which is fine for my needs.

3 words and 2 symbols

```bsh
$ diceware -n3 -s2
DemandingWhimsical*a1iar
```

I am sure there are at least 100 more, of which 74% are written in nodejs, because, uh.. well that's what they do. Whichever you do decide upon, I would prioritize built-in upcase/downcase, because you will have those contraints at some point, and performing either of those is annoyingly long in posix shell.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

The Unix philosophy of "many small tools that do one thing well" serves you very well in this case.

- `/dev/urandom` is a stream of [random](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) "bytes" (which include non-printable characters)
- `base64` [encodes byte data into](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) `[A-Za-z0-9/+]` (which is entirely printable)
- `dd` copies input to output applying modifiers given as arguments (which can include block size and block count)

OSX

```
base64     < /dev/urandom | dd bs=1k count=1
```

Linux

```
base64 -w0 < /dev/urandom | dd bs=1k count=1
```

Notes:

- If you need a subset of the characters, you can insert a modifier in the pipe.

  - Ex: `tr -d '[A-Z/+]'` to get rid of capital letters and `+` and `/`
- You can set the `bs` (block size) to whatever length you need.
- On Linux, `base64` wraps to 76 columns by default and must be reset with `-w0` unless you want that.

Answer (score 2):

I got my way with `grep`:

```
grep -ao '[!-~]' < /dev/urandom | head -32 | tr -d '\n' ; echo ""
```

Without special characters:

```
grep -ao '[A-Za-z0-9]' < /dev/urandom | head -32 | tr -d '\n' ; echo ""
```

`head` defines the length of the string.

Comment: If using [T]csh, the exclamation mark must be escaped: '[\!-~]'

Answer (score 1):

I maintain [`secpwgen` in Alpine Linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=secpwgen&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) & keep the [sources on my Github](https://github.com/itoffshore/secpwgen).

It can produce random strings or diceware phrases:

```
musl64 [~]$ secpwgen
USAGE: secpwgen <-p[e] | -A[adhsy] | -r | -s[e]> N

PASSPHRASE of N words from Diceware dictionary
  -p    generate passphrase
  -pe   generate enhanced (with symbols) passphrase

SKEY PASSWORD of N words from S/Key dictionary
  -s    generate passphrase
  -se   generate enhanced (with symbols) passphrase

ASCII RANDOM of N elements (at least one option MUST be present)
  -A    Each letter adds the following random elements in output:
    a    alphanumeric characters
    d    decimal digits
    h    hexadecimal digits
    s    special characters
    y    3-4 letter syllables

RAW RANDOM
  -r    output BASE64 encoded string of N random BITS
  -k    output koremutake encoding of N random BITS
```

To generate a 13 character random string you would use:

```
musl64 [~]$ secpwgen -Aas 13
----------------
WK5#*V<]M3<CU ;ENTROPY=67.21 bits
----------------
INFO: destroying random number generator.
INFO: zeroing memory.

musl64 [~]$ secpwgen -Aa 13
----------------
GP0FIEBM9Y3BT ;ENTROPY=67.21 bits
----------------
INFO: destroying random number generator.
INFO: zeroing memory.
```

For users to remember a password use the diceware phrases:

```
musl64 [~]$ secpwgen -p 5
----------------
wq seen list n8 kerr  ;ENTROPY=65.00 bits
----------------
INFO: destroying random number generator.
INFO: zeroing memory.
```

I personally like:

```
musl64 [~]$ secpwgen -r 512
----------------
h62lL7G4gwh3/j9c7YteQvVXoqJrQKKPWVR3Lt7az36DcfWZWtUgBT19iwmJBwP4UahNzPe7qYD7OcklUFpCzQ== ;ENTROPY=512.00 bits
----------------
INFO: destroying random number generator.
INFO: zeroing memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Only using `head` y `md5sum` to generate hex passwords of length 22:

```
 head -c 2048 /dev/urandom | md5sum | head -c 22 ; echo
```

Ultra secure? Maybe not. Easy? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

With a short [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```
len=20
arr=( {33..126} ) arrcount=${#arr[@]}
for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
    printf \\$(printf '%03o' ${arr[RANDOM%arrcount]})
done; echo
```

If you prefer without specials characters, use:

```
arr=( {48..57} {65..90} {97..122} )
```

This is ascii decimal codes ranges, see [man ascii](https://helpmanual.io/man7/ascii/)

Answer (score 0):

My way for a very secure password (where 16 is the pw length):

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd [:graph:]|head -c 16
```

Example result:

```
jT@s_Nx]gH<wL~W}
```

Or alternatively, to generate multiple passwords:

cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd [:graph:]|fold -w 16|head -6

Example result:

```
7ck%G7'|f&}_8(]s
<?*]E.CG[NB'gK#A
:tF-WPTOa3!i7S(h
2xy(>=%3=Kb1B$`6
*98Lf{d?Jzb}6q1\
E7uCEAN2Hz]]y|5*
```

Little less secure (smaller character set):

```
cat /dev/urandom |base64 -w 0|fold -w 16|head -6
```

Example result:

```
rJqYxYZLOTV+A45w
PUKQ+BoBf6yfZw5m
+LRfpsN9CsLRiN8V
yMS6zDpL6NHmG17s
yTUWPG7Rum97schi
cognvjVwaKaAyPRK
```

Comment: ```cat /dev/urandom | tr``` has already been given as an answer multiple times — including one that uses `[:graph:]`.  `urandom` → `base64` has also already been given.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers so far are truly cross-OS.

The main flaws are represented by the locale definition (MacOS case) and `tr` being unable to recognize intervals of characters (Solaris case).

You should try [shlibs](https://shlibs.net). It's fresh and truly cross-OS.
The code to get a random string is `shlibs str005` (`./shlibs str005`).

Get a random string of 50 chars, include puntuation, exclude numbers:

```
shlibs str005 50 -p -xd
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the `/dev/urandom` method but using `openssl rand`.

Generate random bytes large enough such that after filtering down to the desired characters, you still meet the required length.

Here, I generate 1000 random bytes for 10 alphanumeric characters `a-zA-Z0-9`:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 < <(openssl rand 1000) | head -c10
```

Note that the above uses process substitution `<(...)`. If your shell doesn't support it, you can create a temporary file:

```
openssl rand 1000 > random.tmp
LC_ALL=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 < random.tmp | head -c10
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Bash script based on answer by [@Gilles Quénot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722319/133353).

#### Example:

---

```bash
chmod +x './rand_string.sh';

# Generate 1 string of length 64.
./rand_string.sh;

# Generate 1 string of length 32.
./rand_string.sh 32;

# Generate 4 strings of length 25.
./rand_string.sh 25 4;
```

#### Script ("`rand_string.sh`")

---

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -eu;

# Constants
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

declare -r _chars=(
    {48..57}   # 0-9
    {65..90}   # A-Z
    {97..122}  # a-z
#   {33..47}   # !"#$%&'()*+,-./
#   {58..64}   # :;<=>?@
#   {91..96}   # [\]^_`
#   {123..126} # {|}~
);

declare -r _lengthDefault=64;
declare -r _countDefault=1;

# Functions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

Main_generateString()
{
    # Options

    declare length="$1";
    shift || true;

    # Main

    declare charCount="${#_chars[@]}";
    declare i;

    for (( i=0; i < length; i++ ));
    do
        declare charHex; charHex="$( printf -- '%x' "${_chars[RANDOM%charCount]}"; )";
        printf -- "\\x${charHex}";
    done;
}

# Main
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

main()
{
    # Options

    declare length="${1:-$_lengthDefault}";
    shift || true;
    declare count="${1:-$_countDefault}";
    shift || true;

    # Main

    declare i;

    for (( i=0; i < count; i++ ));
    do
        Main_generateString "$length";
        printf -- '\n';
    done;
}

main "$@";
```

Answer (score -1):

For lengths between 1 and 32, you can use `uuidgen` from `libuuid` or `util-linux`, simply replacing `<LENGTH>` below:

```
uuidgen -r | tr -d '-' | head -c <LENGTH>

# or

random=$(uuidgen -r | tr -d '-') && echo "${random:0:<LENGTH>}"
```

**Note:** 6–7 of 128 bits are pre-determined and fixed.