# Using sed to replace "A" with a "B" or "C"

Tags: sed, random

This should be straight-forward, but I cannot figure it out. If I want to replace an A or B with a C using sed the code could potentially be:

```
$ echo AAXXAAYYBB | sed 's/[AB]/C/g'
CCXXCCYYCC
```

This results in all A's and B's converted to C's.

What I'd like to do is replace "A" with either one of two (or potentially more) variables:

Input:

```
AAXXAAYYBB
```

Code:

```
sed 's/A/[BC]/g'
```

Output (where the substitution of B or C is random):

```
BCXXCBYYBB
```

But this code will only change A's to...

```
$ echo AAXXAAYYBB | sed 's/A/[BC]/g'
[BC][BC]XX[BC][BC]YYBB
```

I'm trying to avoid PERL here if possible.  Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The replacement text in the `s` command in `sed` is _text_, not an expression.

Comment: It would be fairly easy to make the replacements *alternate* between B and C (using conditional branching)

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for reviewing my question.  I am going to try to see if I can make this work without using perl based on your suggestions.  I am trying write a .sh that I hope anyone would be able to modify.  If I have to add perl, it might be a little complicated for potential users.

Comment: Since the replacement string has to be *randomly* chosen from `B` and `C`, you can use just `s/A/C/g`; you're just [*randomly*](https://xkcd.com/221/) choosing `C` every time. Seriously, if you want to simulate some mutation or such, you should try a bit harder to define your problem and requirements.

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to avoid using perl (not PERL) for this?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to replace the **first** match of an string with:

```
${str/A/...}
```

And, it is possible to generate a random (not a cryptographic secure number) value with:

```
r=(B C)
${r[RANDOM%2]}
```

Each time the variable `r` is expanded.

An exact equivalent operation but a lot faster to implement is an AND to extract the last bit of the value: `${r[RANDOM&1]}`

So:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=AAXXAAYYBB
r=(B C)

while [ "${str%"${str#*A}"}" ]; do      # while there is an A to change
    str=${str/A/"${r[RANDOM&1]}"}
done

echo "str=$str"
```

Will generate a random result each time it is called.

Posixly

```
#!/bin/sh

str=AAXXAAYYZZAAA

while [ "${str%"${str#*A}"}" ]; do             # while there is an A.
    r=$(od -An -tu1 -N 1 /dev/urandom)         # get one random byte
    r=$((r&1))                                 # Is it even or odd?
    if [ "$r" -eq 0 ]; then s=B; else s=C;fi   # Select B or C 
    str="${str%%A*}${s}${str#*A}"              # Change the string.
done

echo "str=$str"
```

Perhaps the random byte could be read with a simpler (but more cryptic) that most of time use the faster builtin printf:

```
r=$(printf '%d\n' "'$(head -c1 /dev/urandom)")
```

Answer (score 5):

Not Sed, but avoids Perl:

```
$ echo AAXXAAYYBB | gawk '
    BEGIN{srand()} 
    {
      n = patsplit($0,a,/A/,s); 
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s", rand() < 0.5 ? "B" : "C", s[i]); 
      print ""
    }
  '
CBXXCCYYBB
```

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of ways to skin this particular cat once we resort to scripting, but here is something I threw together - It may not be pretty, (and relies on a bash shell!) but it might help you out:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEXT="AAXXAAYYBB"

echo "Start: $TEXT"

# So long as there are un-converted 'A' in the input string...
while [[ "$TEXT" =~ A ]]
do
        # .. convert one 'A' to a random choice of either 'B' or 'C'
        TEXT=$(echo $TEXT | sed -e "s/A/$(((RANDOM%2>0))&&echo B || echo C)/")

        # lets show how we are progressing...
        echo "Progress: $TEXT"
done

# No more 'A' in the input string, we are done:
echo "End: $TEXT"
```

Example output:

First run:

```
Start: AAXXAAYYBB
Progress: BAXXAAYYBB
Progress: BBXXAAYYBB
Progress: BBXXBAYYBB
Progress: BBXXBCYYBB
End: BBXXBCYYBB
```

Second run:

```
Start: AAXXAAYYBB
Progress: CAXXAAYYBB
Progress: CBXXAAYYBB
Progress: CBXXCAYYBB
Progress: CBXXCBYYBB
End: CBXXCBYYBB
```

Comment: Nice idea (+1)! You should quote your variables though (`echo "$TEXT"`) to preserve whitespace. Also, even better is `printf` to deal with escape characters. Even better is a herestring (`<<< "$TEXT"`) to not open a new process.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more "straightforward" to replace ***A or B*** with C than to replace *A with **B or C***, as the **or** in the former case has nothing to do with randomness, while in the latter it's based on it. So while the former could be broken down into two simple steps:

1. replace A with C
2. replace B with C

In the latter case there's the whole lot of deciding which one should be the replacement in every particular case, B or C? What's the basis? How random should the randomness be?

`sed` doesn't offer any random operations as far as I know. (While Perl should be a good tool.)

See related:

- [How to generate a random string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string)
- And other [random](/questions/tagged/random) tagged questions

Answer (score 0):

## perl loves regex

If you choose to use perl, you'll find the `e` flag useful for substitutions.  This `e`valuates the replacement as code.

e.g.:
`s/A/c("BC")/eg` where c is subroutine to pull a random char from a string.

Hard coded with A->[BC] :

```perl
sub c {
  if(my $s = shift) {
    my $index = int(rand(length($s)));
    return substr($s, $index, 1);
  }
}

while(<<>>){
  print s/A/C("BC")/eg
}
```

Or compressed into a not terribly pretty one-liner. (actually two-liner for clarity):

```
perl -E 'sub c {if(my $l = shift) {substr($l, int(rand(length($l))), 1);}}' -plE 's/A/c(BCBBB)/eg'
```

Expanded into a random_replace:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "usage: random_replace regex string_of_replacement_chars\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my $search = shift;
my $replace = shift;

sub c {
  if (my $s = shift) {
    my $index = int(rand(length($s)));
    substr($s, $index, 1);
  }
}

while(<<>>)
{
  s/$search/c($replace)/eg;
  print;
}
```

```
% echo "AAAAAA" | ./random_replace A BC
CCCCBC

% echo "AAAAAA" | ./random_replace A BC
BBBBBC
```

As an extra bonus, the search can be a regex.  Let's say you want to replace A or B with C or D:

```
% echo "AAABBB" | ./random_replace '[A-B]' CD
CCCDCD

% echo "AAABBB" | ./random_replace '[A-B]' CD
DDCCDD
```